# Raspberry Pi & Blend Micro : can't connect with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, raspberry-pi

Recently got a Blend Micro for a project and I need a raspberry pi to initiate a bluetooth connection with it.

For that I installed BlueZ 5.2 on raspberry and i used this command to detect the Blend Micro :

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 lescan
```

I correctly detect the Blend micro then i use the gatttool command :

```
sudo gatttool -i hcitool hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -I  
(where the XX corresponds to the Blend MAC address)
```

But when I initiate the connection by typing connect it says "Host is down" :

```
$ sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -I
[   ][XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]> connect
Connecting... connect error: Host is down (112) 
[   ][XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]>
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix that ? Tried many things without any results though...

Regards, RaZZeR

Answer (score 3):

When you are connecting, you need to add "-t random" to your command line.

Comment: Thank you for this, this solved the issue for me with bluez 5.33.
Additionally, my BT adapter was not starting with the OS, I had to manually do 'hciconfig device up' before running hcitool or gatttool